# Do planetary resources respawn?

Tags: star-trader-rpg

I've been slowly clearing out all the high value low/medium risk planets in the galaxy via exploration.  Do these planets ever regain more resources for me to exploit or do I have to start going after the high risk planets?

Comment: Hm... This game has clearly been updated quite a bit since I last played...

Comment: @SaintWacko maybe you have the free version?  The paid version has lot more content

Comment: No, I definitely have the paid version, it's just been quite a while since I've played it